# Multiple RadUpload Control in One Page

Tags: asp.net, radupload

I have an aspx page that uses master page. In the papx page, I load a user control containing 2 RadUpload controls (Rad1 and Rad2). User can choose to upload the file either using the first RadUpload or the second RadUpload and there is certain validation applied for each RadUpload.

The weird thing happened is that when I upload file using Rad2 (second RadUpload), the RadUpload.UploadedFiles for the first RadUpload is there (count = 1). Instead of the file being uploaded by Rad2, it is detected as if it is uploaded from Rad1, so my validation failed.

Does someone encounter this problem before? This is a very weird thing and I've spent almost 1 and a half day fixing this without knowing what happened to the control

Answer (score 1):

Please have in mind that RadAsyncUpload will try to use FileApi, Adobe Flash Player (v.10 or newer) or Silverlight for the file selection dialog to allow selecting multiple files. If neither of them is available, RadAsyncUpload will gracefully degrade to single file selection.

Answer (score 0):

I have three radupload/progress controls on a webpage and they work perfectly.

My suggestion would be to place them explicitly in the page itself instead of within a user control.

I did not try to replicate your issue as I am in the middle of development myself but I just wanted to share something with you that worked the first time.